# Testing Sharepoint 2013 Apps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Can you suggest how to proceed with testing **apps** in share point 2013 manually or via automation.

Answer (score 0):

For Unit testing:
It all depends on the technology which the app is using and type of the SharePoint APP. Basically, for Cloud-based apps you would test them in the same way as you would test standalone web application that is using same web technology.